# Where can I ask a deobfuscation question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question on codegolf.se, and was advised that Code Golf is for contests and that I could try Stack Overflow.

So I asked it on Stack Overflow instead

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241222/how-does-this-bitcoin-address-generator-in-obfuscated-python-work

The question attracted 6 down votes and 3 close votes in a few short minutes, I've since deleted it.

Where does this question fit on the Stack Exchange Network? Or doesn't it fit anywhere?

Comment: "How does this code work" is always "too broad" for SO, and I don't think there is any other SE site where it is on topic. You can however ask SO about small, isolated snippets of obfuscated code instead - try to figure it out yourself and only ask a question when you've stumbled on a sufficiently small part of the program you can't make sense of.

Comment: You may wish to help with the [Code Understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding) area 51 proposal.  The current top example question is [What exactly does {insert overly obfuscated code here} do?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding/69244#69244)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your question on Stack Overflow was that it was **too broad**. De-obfuscating such code is a multi-step process, and it isn't clear what parts you need help with.

Specific questions about that chunck *may* be suitable, but you had shown no efforts to even begin unraveling that knot yourself. I think it was the lack of effort on your part that attracted the downvotes.

There currently are no Stack Exchange sites where asking a full *unravel this obfuscated piece of code and explain to me what exactly it does* type questions.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. As I barely know where to start, I'm going to give up. Pretty cool piece of code though.